# SWIGTYPE declaring typedef before the implementation

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I have the next definition in a file:

File: one.h

```
typedef struct example example;
```

And in other file I have the implementation of the struct:

File: two.h

```
typedef struct example1{
     int four;
} example1;

struct example {
  int one;
  example1 four;
};
```

File: swig.i

¿?

File wrapper.java

```
 class SWIGTYPE_P_example;

  // I want to have: class example;
```

When I compile, swig generate the class `SWIGTYPE_p_example`, instead of the object
example.

I understand that the declaration of my struct is unknow and this is the reason because I have the SWIGTYPE, but, are there any way to have into the wrapper the correct class?

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming this is C because of the `typedef`? (Also did you mean `SWIGTYPE_p_example`?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution was to redefine my typedef in the my swig.i file

File: swig.i

typedef struct example1{
     int four;
}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an interface file that looks something like:

```
%module test

// Forward declare, SWIG knows nothing more:
struct example;
typedef struct example example;

void foo(example *ex);
example *bar();
```

(Or possibly uses a `%include` directive to bring in a header file) then you can cause SWIG to do more than its default by something as simple as adding:

```
struct example {};
```

before the first mention of example in your interface file. This is enough to cause SWIG to treat it as more than just a pointer. It can be perfectly sensible to offer SWIG partial definitions<sup>1</sup> of just the parts of a `struct` (or `class` in C++) that you care about - in this instance it sounds like there's nothing in your real definition of `struct example` that you care about.

<sup>1</sup> There are some problems with C++ types that are abstract or don't have a default constructor.

Comment: it´s not exactly this scenary, I need the definition of the struct before to know the content of this because of restrictions with internal content of this one. I mean, I need to have the typedef struct example example; in a file.h, and the struct {} later on other file1.h. Sorry but I don´t know how to use %module or %include. I´m talking of .h not .i, because I want my .i was generated automatically regarding to my files.h

Comment: @jegumi - can you edit your question to show a *minimal* example of then? Otherwise if I updated my answer I'm still going to be guessing as to what your scenario really is.

Comment: I tried to edit the post to explain better, sorry if I didn´t get, but I´m new with swig. Anyway thanks for your answers. I suppose I have to do something in my swig.i to fix the problem :(

Comment: thanks for your help, and sorry because of muy bad explanation. You put me on the correct way :D